# form submition after using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I have two pages in php. First page is the following:

```
<?php

// --- please consider that my form is inside a while statement...


<form action='deletepost.php' method='post' >
  <input type='hidden' name='var' value='$comment_id;'>
  <input type='submit' value='delete' >
</form>

?>
```

and page deletepost.php is the following:

```
<?php

    $comment = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['var']);
    echo" $comment ";

    // --- then starts successfully the delete process I have created...

?>
```

So first page includes a form button delete that when I press it passes the value that I want to page deletepost.php successfully (I use echo to see it as you can see). 
I have decided to use a javascript lightbox for my form in first page. I have changed my code to that:

```
<?php

<a href = javascript:void(0) onclick = document.getElementById('light').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'><h2><font color=green size=3>Delete All</font></h2></a>
<div id=light class=white_content>


<form action='deletepost.php' method='post' >
  <input type='hidden' name='var' value='$comment_id'>
  <input type='submit' value='delete' onClick=submit(); >
</form>


<a href=javascript:void(0) onclick=document.getElementById('light').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'><button style='margin-left:250px; width:95px;'>Cancel</button></a>
</div>
<div id=fade class=black_overlay></div>
```

the problem is that after using javascript, values are not passed to deletepost.php .Any idea why this might happend?

Comment: <input type='submit' value='delete' onClick=submit(); > remove onclick  event from this line

Comment: i did it still nothing

Comment: close the  first <?php tag with ?> in next line and use as follow <input type='hidden' name='var' value=<?=$comment_id?>>
  <input type='submit' value='delete' />

Comment: I thing that the problem comes from href of javascript lightbox that probably not allow passing the variable to next page

Comment: It is outside a form, what is it supossed to do

Comment: yes but the point is that if I remove href javascript lightbox I see that it works successfully

Comment: so remove the href, I actually do not understand what is your real problem. Once you click on the button/submit which is inside the form, it will send you the `$_POST['var']` to the next page. What exactly you are trying to do? Do you want to click on `Delete all` and something to happen? Where are you clicking, and where are you checking that the post array does not contain `var`

Comment: When click on delete all the lightbox appears and then click delete button of form and then pass variable to next page

Comment: So which of these steps do not work?

Comment: when using lightbox and then press delete it is not passing the value to next page.

Comment: I tested your code and I have no problems using it. It actually pass the variable.

Comment: then probably the problem comes from my while statement in which it is the form

Comment: See my edited answer, you should stop messing PHP and HTML. See how I did the things inside a while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see no point of having javascript over a submit button. You either do it on `<a>` or `<button>`, and you should refer to the form name.

```
<form name='form1' action='deletepost.php' method='post'>

...


<button onclick='document.form1.submit()'>delete</button>
```

Calling `submit()` only will do nothing, because there is no such built in alone method. You can aliase the refering in a wrapper method

```
function submit() {
    document.form1.submit();
}
```

---

Here are my tests:

test1.php:

```
<?php $comment_id = 1 ?>
<?php while($comment_id < 10): ?>
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('light<?=$comment_id;?>').style.display='block';document.getElementById('fade<?=$comment_id;?>').style.display='block'"><h2><font color=green size=3>Delete All</font></h2></a>
    <div id="light<?=$comment_id;?>" class="white_content" style="display: none">


    <form action="test2.php" method="post" name="form1">
      <input type="hidden" name="var" value="<?=$comment_id;?>" />
      <button onClick="document.form1.submit();">Delete</button>
    </form>


    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('light<?=$comment_id;?>').style.display='none';document.getElementById('fade<?=$comment_id;?>').style.display='none'"><button style="margin-left:250px; width:95px;">Cancel</button></a>
    </div>
    <div id=fade class=black_overlay></div>
<?php $comment_id++; ?>
<?php endwhile;?>
```

It generates me 9 comment lightboxes. On fifth one I click on `Delete all` it expands the button `Delete`. Then I click the button and it redirects me to `test2.php` Where I have

```
<?php var_dump($_POST); ?>
```

And the output in the webpage is:

```
array (size=1)
  'var' => string '5' (length=1)
```

Comment: I am just using a simple javascript lightbox how is it possible to not allow me passing the var to next page?

Comment: I want to pass $comment_id to next page and when using the href javascript for the lightbox it is not passing it

Comment: Where does $comment_id comes from? Isn't it just `$comment` ?

Comment: it comes above from my code and it is passed to form at name='var' value='$comment_id'

Comment: dear friend thank you for your excellent help...it works thanks to you!

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the `onClick` property for your submit input.  ESPECIALLY if you don't actually have a `submit` method defined anywhere in your JS.  Setting that attribute could be enough to stop the default submit behavior of the form and will stop your php from running.